# Bash -Extract characters from string

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed

Suppose I have the following variable

$string = 'cat somecommandhere'

Now the output of the above `cat` command is

```
test="Thanks serverfault"
```

I want to extract the value between the quotes and store it in the same variable `$string`, including the quotes.  I want string to contain value below:

```
$string = "Thanks serverfault"
```

How can this be done with `sed` or `grep` but not `awk`.  I haven't learned `awk` yet.

Comment: Why are you resistant to learning what is likely the best tool to accomplish this?

Comment: i prefer to learn sed and awk separately so that i don't get confused

Comment: Part of learning how to use those two tools is recognizing the best one for the job; it's not like learning a programming language, and it makes things much harder on yourself if you try to use the wrong one. It's also worth noting that `cut` is a specialized tool with few options to learn, as opposed to `awk` and `sed` which have their own associated sub-languages.

Comment: If it can't be done in `sed` or `grep` you guys should just say so. And then present a case for `awk`.

Comment: It is unclear what language the code shown is written in.  Is it PHP or Perl?

Answer (score 6):

I'll use `cut`, since it's fairly easy to deducate that `-f2` means "the second part" and `-d'"'` means cut on the double quotation mark.

```
$ output='test="Thanks serverfault"'
$ string=$( echo $output | cut -f2 -d'"' )
$ echo $string
Thanks serverfault
```

If you really want the quotes, you can just add them back yourself, it just makes the answer look more confusing than it needs to be.

If you really want to use `sed` (lucky for you, this keeps the quotes too):

```
$ output='test="Thanks serverfault"'
$ string=$( echo $output | sed 's/^test=//' )
$ echo $string
"Thanks serverfault"
```

Explanation of `sed`:

```
                           s/^test=//
  string find/replace mode ^ |     ^ replace with nothing
                             starts with test=
```

Comment: Thanks Jay dude i am learning sed btw and was expecting an answer involving sed

Comment: dude sorry for not saying this in thread but there might be other text in the file that i will edit via bash ....just give me a sed command that will extract the value between the first " " in file

Comment: `grep` has an option for only returning the matched string.  `echo $output | grep -o '"[^"]*"'` would achieve what you do above with `sed`.

Comment: @Ladadadada, thanks, I didn't know that. Werulz, I hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 3):

No need for sed; bash and sh have variable modifiers built in:

```
$ output='test="Thanks serverfault"'
$ string=\"${output#*\"}
$ string=${string%\"*}\"
$ echo $string
"Thanks serverfault"
```

# removes prefixes, % is suffixes.

This should be faster than calling external programs.

Answer (score 0):

Other users gave probably the best answers: no need of sed.
But if you need it this should work:

```
sed 's/.*=//' #this will remove everything before (inclusive) of the equal.
```

Answer (score 0):

With pcregrep:

```
string=$(eval " $string" | pcregrep -Mo '(?s)"(\\.|[^"])*"')
```

Would evaluate the contents of `$string` as shell code, and extract from its output the double-quoted strings, handling possibly escaped `"`s and `\`, which would then be stored newline-separated in `$string`.

For instance with `file=some-file string='cat < "$file"'`, where `some-file` contains:

```
test="Thanks serverfault"
test2="with \"quotes\" and backslash\\" test3="multi
line"
```

`$string` would end up containing:

```
"Thanks severfault"
"with \"quotes\" and backslash\\"
"multi
line"
```